# Duda sobre records de DNS y dominios

Tags: dns, dominio

Mi servidor me permite configurar los DNS de un dominio y mi proveedor de dominio me deja hacer lo mismo.

La pregunta es: ¿Debo configurar en ambas zonas? ¿Puedo mantener un dominio sin zona DNS (minimo) y que tome una configuración de mi servidor? La idea es que a mis clientes les pida que cambien solo los nameserver de su dominio pero el resto de records de los DNS los tome de mi servidor. ¿Es posible?

PD: Ya se que configurando la zona de DNS desde el panel del dominio todo funciona, pero necesito la menos intervención posible del lado de mis clientes.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Tus clientes no tienen que configurar nada con respecto a los DNS. Si tienes el dominio en un proveedor y el servidor en otro, tienes que configurar los DNS en el proveedor de dominio para que apunten a los IP del servidor. No hay más.

Comment: Tecnicamente pensaba que es automatico pero no logro que tome la configuracion de mi servidor (VPS con CentOs). Si lo configuro del proveedor de dominio todo funciona, pero no si solo cambio los nameserver. Y tienen los mismos records. seguire probando. gracias.

Comment: El cambio de DNS tarda varias horas en propagarse, a veces tarda incluso uno, o dos días (en raros casos). Hay páginas que te ayudan a seguir la propagación de los DNS, por ejemplo [esta](https://dnsmap.io). El cambio va ocurriendo por zonas o regiones. Como dije antes, lo único que tienes que hacer es poner el DNS de tu servidor en la configuración del proveedor de dominios. Por ejemplo tengo un dominio en Namecheap, y el hosting en Bluehost. Lo único que he hecho ha sido poner los DNS de Bluehost en la configuración de mi dominio (en Namecheap), en Bluehost no tengo que cambiar nada.